# I am trying to connect firebase to my project on vscode firebase login

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

I am trying to login to firebase on my vscode it shows I am login but this came up

```
  firebase-tools update check failed             │
│            Try running with sudo or get access             │
│            to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\onuch\.config
```

I am trying to login to firebase on my vscode